# Session expiring for some minutes automatically in yii2

Tags: php, session, yii2

I want following features on Yii2 website:

1) I want to make the users visiting the website without signing in again, once he logged in and he didn't log out yet.
To do this, I made a configuration as follows:

```
'user' => [
  'identityClass'   => 'common\models\User',
  'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

2) But in this case, session is expired after a while if a user is idle for some minutes.
On our website, the user should upload a video, but video uploading takes a long time, even one hour. So there can be no activity for one hour, but after uploading a video is done, `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` returns `false`. So the next process is not going on.

I want to resolve this problem, and I want to increase session expiration time to more than 5 hrs.

Please help me. I am now using Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

Assign proper value to authTimeout in your config

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 60,
    ],
```

see this ref for more

and eval also absoluteAuthTimout

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I set authTimeout as 36000, then will this resolve a problem completely?

Comment: 36000 are 10 Hours  .. anyway i have update the answer take a look to absoluteAuthTimeout too

Comment: Thanks for your comment again. I know about absoluteAuthTimeout, too, and I have ever used that before, so I am clear about that parameter. But I don't want to use this because it makes a user logged out regardless of his activity. I am really interested in authTimeout. If you make sure that authTimeout can resolve my problem, then I would be very happy. Thanks.